Which of these chess positions is legal?
This little quiz should be a bit easier than my previous puzzles so feel free to join in!
Simply put: Which of these chess positions is legal?

To be clear, I consider a position to be legal, if it can be reached from the starting position by legal moves. There may be more (or less!) than one legal position among the four, so please provide your reasoning to settle each of the four cases in your answer.

I think

 only the top right is reachable

Reason

 There are two captures available to white and one to black. These must produce 5 passed pawns for white and 4 passed pawns for black. That is 3 passed pawns per capture which happens to be the maximum. The maximum is attained by pawn-pawn capture. For example, a4xb5 creates two white passed pawns in the b file and one black passed pawn in the a file. For this maneuver two adjacent files with both pawns present are necessary and all 4 pawns are  consumed. In the two positions on the left it can only have been carried out twice which is not enough.


 Note that all 3 promotions afforded by one pawn-pawn capture happen on squares of the same colour. Therefore at least 8 of the 13 bishops in the bottom right position would have to be the same square colour which is not the case.


 For knights this constraint does not apply, and nothing else prevents one from reaching the top right position.


 Proof game: 1. h4 h5 2. g4 g5 3. f4 f5 4. e4 e5 5. d4 d5 6. c4 c5 7. b4 b5 8. a4 a5 9. hxg5 bxc4 10. exf5 e4 11. b5 h4 12. f6 c3 13. g6 c4 14. b6 c2 15. f5 c3 16. g5 h3 17. Be3 c1=N 18. b7 Nc6 19. b8=N Ne5 20. Nf3 h2 21. Rg1 h1=N 22. g7 Nh6 23. g8=N c2 24. Nc6 Nb3 25. Nb4 c1=N 26. Nh4 Kd7 27. f7 Ng3 28. g6 Be7 29. f8=N+ Kd6 30. f6 Nhf5 31. Ne6 Nh5 32. Nh6 Ne2 33. Bc1 Nc5 34. f7 e3 35. f8=N Nef4 36. g7 e2 37. Kd2 e1=N 38. Nfg6 Nh3 39. Ng5 Nc2 40. Nc3 Na3 41. Ke1 Nb5 42. g8=N Bf8 43. Nge4+ Kd7 44. Nf4 Ng5 45. Ng4 Ke8 46. N8f6+ Ke7 47. Ne8 Kf7 48. N8d6+ Ke7 49. Nc4 Ke8 50. Nce2 Rh7 51. Rh1 Rh6 52. Ng1 Rh8


Your "same color.Therefore" argument is not correctly formulated - e.g. c(by black)+f,g(by white) fails with 6-7

@Retudin I'm not sure I understand. Did you perhaps miss the "square" in front of the "colour"? There are 6/7 bishops belonging to either player, yes, but 8 or more are either confined to black squares or white squares.

You can have both 6black-7white-square and 6black-7white-color distributed simultaneously. But you end up with 2(in my example above) or 4 black-colored-black-squared bishops.

@Retudin maybe I'm just being very dense, but I'm 99% sure my argument is right. We start with two black squared and two white squared bishops. Now, for example, white captures c4xb5, this creates two white passed pawns on the b file and one black passed pawn on the c file. Their promotion squares are b8 and c1 which are both black, so this creates 3 black squared bishops and 0 white squared bishops. In particular, mod 3 nothing changes so neither 6 nor 7 are reachable as a total.

Very good, well done! And no worries, your argument is completely correct :)

I'm the one that is very dense. Sorry, I should have doubted myself more before commenting.
